# Remover 'cabeçalho' TabHost Android

Tags: java, android

Olá, pessoal. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em android usando TabHost. O problema é que eu não queria a parte superior da tab porque ocupa muito espaço. Já procurei bastante na internet e não encontrei nada que me ajudasse. Alguém sabe se é possível fazer isso. Se sim, alguma luz?

Nessa imagem dá pra entender melhor o que eu quero. Eu quero eliminar essa barra que tem "A" e "B".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso vc não precisava utilizar o TabHost, pois esse gerenciador que inclui essa barra que vc quer tirar. Vc poderia utilizar apenas um [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

Comment: Exatamente o que eu fiz. Comentei a parte que criava esse TabHost e funcionou direitinho. Muito obrigada!